# Laravel Not Updating Item Using Eloquent

Tags: php, sql, laravel, eloquent, laravel-5

I'm trying to add flagging functionality into my web app, and it seems to only be half working. I can flag a particular resource, add my reason for the flag as well as other comments just fine. Once I view all the flagged resources, the reasons and comments are saved and correct, but the resource on which I flagged are all the same, in this case 'Salvation Army'. For example I have 4 flagged resources all of them show different reasons for being flagged, but the resources itself are all the same even when I didn't flag 'Salvation Army'.

Here's some of my code, hopefully you can help me figure out why Eloquent isn't updating my item in the database:

**Resource Model**

```html
class Resources extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'Resources';

    protected $primaryKey = 'Resource_ID';

    public $timestamps = false;

    protected $fillable = [
        'Name',
        'Description',
        'Misc_Info',
        'Flagged'
    ];

    protected $guarded = [];

    //referencing the pivot table for Flagged and Resources
    public function flags()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Models\Flagged', 'FlaggedResources', 'Resource_ID', 'Flag_ID');
    }
```

**Flag Model**

```html
class Flagged extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'Flagged';

    protected $primaryKey = 'Flag_ID';

    public $timestamps = false;

    protected $fillable = [
        'Flag_Reason',
        'Other_Comments'
    ];

    protected $guarded = [];
    //references the pivot table for Flagged and Resources
    public function resource()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Models\Resource', 'FlaggedResources');
    }
}
```

**FlaggedResources Model**

```html
class FlaggedResources extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'FlaggedResources';

    public $timestamps = false;

    protected $fillable = [
        'Resource_ID',
        'Flag_ID'
    ];
    protected $guarded = [];
}
```

**FlagsController**

```html
public function index()
    {
        $resource =  Resources::where('Flagged', 1)->with('flags')->get();
        $flag = Flagged::all();
        return view('pages.flags', ['flagged' => $resource], ['flag' => $flag]);
    }

    public function addFlag($id)
    {
        $resource = Resources::where('Resource_ID', '=', $id)->update(array('Flagged' => 1));
        $flag = Flagged::create(Request::all());
        $resource->save();
        $flag->save();
        return back();
    }
```

If the `Flagged=1` it'll show up in the view, if `Flagged=0` it won't show.

**Flags View**

```html
<table class=" display table table-hover table-bordered" , id="flaggedResources">
  <thead>
    <th>Name</th>
    <th>Description</th>
    <th>Flagged Reason</th>
    <th>Other Comments</th>
    <th>Functions</th>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    @foreach ($flagged as $flags) @foreach ($flag as $flaggedRes)
    <tr>
      <td>{{ $flags->Name }}</td>
      <td>{{ $flags->Description }}</td>
      <td>{{ $flaggedRes -> Flag_Reason }}</td>
      <td>{{ $flaggedRes -> Other_Comments }}</td>

      @endforeach @endforeach
  </tbody>
</table>
```

When I check MySQLWorkbench, to check if any changes are made, there are not any changes to my Resources table, but the data is entered into my Flagged table.  The previous developer who tried to work on the flagging functionality hardcoded that 1 into 'Salvation Army' so that's why only that one is flagged in the DB. Also, no data is being inserted into the pivot table.

If anyone could help me with this it would be greatly appreciated, I've been stuck on this problem for about a month.

**EDIT**
I've added some pictures of the Resources and Flagged SQL Table, hopefully it'll help diagnose the problem

[image: Resources Table] [image: Resources Column Settings] [image: Flagged Table]

**EDIT 2**

I figured out why it wasn't updating the Resources table, I had another method called `PostFlag` that was just inserting the `Flag_Reason` and `Other_Comments` and not doing anything with `Resources` and the routes was calling `PostFlag`. Now I'm confused as to how to setup my routes. The route I have now after I edited the `PostFlag` method to update the `Resource` table is

```html
Route::post('resource', ['as' => 'resource', 'uses'=>'FlagsController@postFlag']);
```

If I don't touch the route I get a `Missing argument 1 for App\Http\Controllers\FlagsController::postFlag()` error when I load the Flagged Resources view.  If I edit the route to take in an ID like so `Route::post('resource/{Resource_ID}', ['as' => 'resource', 'uses'=>'FlagsController@postFlag']);` I get a `Missing required parameters for [Route: resource] [URI: resource/{Resource_ID}])`.  Do I need to set up a get route, if so how do I set that up?

Answer (score 0):

To be honest, I am not sure why you are really using a `belongsToMany` relation when a you are creating a New Flag everytime and then associating it with the resource. The **Resources** here `hasMany('App\Models\Flagged')` and **Flagged** `belongsTo('App\Models\Resources')`. But still... I mean, I can't really suggest such a huge database change when you have already decided to go with a pivot table. In any case, I believe will solve everything for you...

#### Part 1

First of all make the following changes

In the class `Resources`

```
public function flags()
{
  return $this->belongsToMany('App\Models\Flagged', 'FlaggedResources')->withPivot(['Resource_ID', 'Flag_ID']);
}
```

In the class `Flagged`

```
public function resources()
{
  return $this->belongsToMany('App\Models\Resource', 'FlaggedResources')->withPivot(['Resource_ID', 'Flag_ID']);
}
```

There is no need of the class `FlaggedResources`. Please **delete** that.

#### Part 2

Now, In the **Controller**

```
public function index()
{
  $resources =  Resources::where('Flagged', 1)->with('flags')->get();
  
  return view('pages.flags', ['resources' => $resources]);
}

public function addFlag($id)
{
  $flag = Flagged::create(Request::all());
  
  $resource = Resources::findOrFail($id);

  $resource->update(array('Flagged' => 1));

  $resource->flags()->attach([$flag->id]);
  
  return back();
}
```

In the **View**

```
@foreach ($resources as $resource)
<tr>
  <td>{{ $resource->Name }}</td>
  <td>{{ $resource->Description }}</td>
  <td>{{ $resource->flags ? $resource->flags->first()->Flag_Reason : 'None' }}</td>
  <td>{{ $resource->flags ? $resource->flags->first()->Other_Comments : 'None' }}</td>
</tr>
@endforeach
```

Hope this helps :)

Comment: Thank you for your help, the `Flag Reason & Other Comments` are inserted into the database, nothing is being inserted into the pivot table `FlaggedResources` and the `Flagged` field in the `Resources` table is unchanged.  I am also getting a syntax error on these lines `<td>{{ $resource->flags ? $resource->flags->first()->Other_Comments }}</td>` it says a `:` is expected after `Other_Comments and Flag_Reason`.

Comment: Ok, so I modified your 2 `<td>` statements to look like this `<td>{{ $resource->flags->Other_Comments }}</td>` the view now loads, but no matter what I flag, nothing goes into the table view, but the reasons and comments are being inserted into the database still.

Comment: @JDubbleU Oh yes, Sry about that.... I forgot to write the **OR** part in the inline condition statement... I have edited my answer (the view section). Can you try again and let me know if it works :)

Comment: I've changed it, but there's no difference in functionality.  The 'Flagged' field in my `Resources` table still stays at 0 instead of updating to 1, and `Flag_Reason and Other_Comments` are being inserted into the `Flagged` table.  I don't know why my `Resources` table isn't updating.